# Angular.js template to plain html

Tags: html, angularjs, templates

I want to know if it is possible to compile a Angular.js template to plain html. for example.

```
//script.js
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.browsers = ['chrome', 'firefox', 'ie'];
}

// template.html
<div ng-app>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="browser in browsers">{{browser}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>chrome</>
        <li>firefox</>
        <li>ie</>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are some way to perform this converssion or some CLI tool for this?
I tried with $compile but the result is not what I want. For Example

```
...
var compiled = $compile('<ul><li ng-repeat="browser in browsers">{{browser}}</li></ul>');
var el = compiled($scope);
console.log(el.html())
...
```

The result is a HTML comment

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, view the page and open the developer tools. In the elements tab, right click `<html>` and click copy as HTML. This copies the HTML for what is currently on screen. You can also copy the HTML for individual components by right clicking them and selecting copy as HTML.